# Laravel custom errors with model injected into controller

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, laravel-5

So I was coming across a problem which I haven't exactly been able to resolve and having no idea where I should start with this.

I know Laravel has a nice `findOrFail()` function but I seem to be unable to use that in my case. So for example I have a route as follow:

```
Route::get('user/{user}', 'UserController@show);
```

My controller

```
public function show(User $user)
{
    //never reaches this section 
}
```

Now this would normally work, but if the record does not exists Laravel throws the error before I get inside the function. Is there a nice and easy way of catching the error without changing my function to

```
public function show($id)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($id)
}
```

I find it much nicer to have the user class in my function parameter and wish not to remove it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [the Laravel Docs for Route Model Binding](//laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-model-binding) (scroll down to the 'Customizing The "Not Found" Behavior' heading):

> If you wish to specify your own "not found" behavior, pass a `Closure` as the third argument to the `model` method:
>
> ```
> $router->model('user', 'App\User', function () {
>     throw new NotFoundHttpException;
> });
> ```

Earlier they specify where to place that code:

> You should define your model bindings in the `RouteServiceProvider::boot` method.

Comment: How stupid that I've missed this, thank you very much it has solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

First time answering a question so bear with me!

You can use a PHP try/catch block. So something like this:

```
try {
        //Your code here
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return \Redirect::to('/users')
            ->with('error', 1)
            ->with('message', 'Error getting your record!');
    }
```

And then in your Laravel blade you can do something like:

```
@if(!empty($error) && $error == 1)
   <div>
      <strong>Uh-Oh!</strong> 
        @if(!empty($message))
            {!! $message !!}
        @endif
   </div>
@endif
```

To display the error. You can also redirect to some error page you want.

Comment: The problem being is that the error is being shown before I can do anything inside my function. Even if I put echo "test"; die; inside my function this won't be shown.

Comment: Well if your code isn't getting to your function, that means there's a problem beforehand! Your route is a GET with an URL parameter of user ID. So your function should read `public function show($userid)` in the first line. Then when you query, you can do something like `$user = User::find($userid)`. Then you can do something like `if($user){ //code }else{//return to users with error}`

Comment: As of Laravel 5 you can also go like `app()->make(\App\Models\User::class)->where('users.id','=',$userid)->get();` which is cleaner I think, you don't have to inject your models.

Comment: As matter of fact, if the record exists you can just use Classname $param in the function as shown in my code and it would work perfectly. It's just that in case the record does not exists laravel automatically generates an error for you. I just want to know where to catch this.